# How to implement HashMap in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have some amount of messages which are coming to my client from the server.
Every messages have an unique key which is possible to be duplicated in messages I have already received. 
Which collection can I use in GWT to avoid duplication?
HashMap seems not to be a case for GWT. Is there any other way to organize it?

Comment: Why can't you use HashMap? If it object duplication you are worried, then shouldn't you use HashSet?

Comment: You can HashMap in GWT without any problem, same as in Java

Answer (score 37):

You can use the standard java.util.HashMap in GWT without problems. Be sure you haven't accidentally imported the com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.HashMap. It happened to me several times while using Eclipse's Organize imports feature..

Comment: I know you posted this two years ago, but why in the world would GWT implement HashMap that is not compatible with... well GWT!?

Comment: The only explanation I found is that the GWT's HashMap is not for client-side compilation but for some other purposes.

Answer (score 13):

For questions like this, you should take a look at the [GWT JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation?hl=en-US). It contains the java classes of the Java runtime library that can be automatically translated by GWT. The link points to the JRE ER for GWT 1.6. to show you that HashMap wasn't just included in the latest version. (The JRE ER for the latest version can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation?hl=en-US))

Answer (score 1):

As xor_eq points you should check the [GWT JRE Emulation Reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) Check the link to the latest version (or the version that you're running). The support for for HashMap was added to GWT sometime ago (in 2.0 I think), so you should have no problem.

Comment: HashMap was already supported in GWT 1.6., but I don't know what the first version was that supported it.